# strange result from js image load, in safari and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I have several images, the width of each image is 1400px, I want after load all images, alert sum width of all images, this is my code:

```
var images = new Array("0.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i = i + 1) {
    $("#img_place").append("<img src='" + images[i] + "'>");
}


var loadedImgsCount = 0;
var imgTotalWidth = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i = i + 1) {

    var currImg = new Image();
    currImg.src = images[i];
    currImg.onload = function() {
        loadedImgsCount = loadedImgsCount + 1;
        imgTotalWidth = imgTotalWidth + currImg.width;
    }

}


interv = setInterval(function() {
    if (images.length === loadedImgsCount) {
        alert(imgTotalWidth );
        clearInterval(interv);
    }
}, 500);
```

and in HTML:

```
 <div id="img_place">
 </div>
```

this code is for example for 3 image, problem is that: in chrome and safari, result from this code is sometimes incorrect: sometimes 1400, sometimes 2800 but sometimes correct: 4200.
In opera and firefox resultat always expected: 4200.
Please tell, where have I error? why my code works in safari and chrome incorrect ?

Comment: Why to you use setInterval ? You could put its code in the onload.

Comment: Always use array literals, never `new Array`. `var images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg"];`

Comment: You know, `loadedImgsCount++` is a lot shorter to write than `loadedImgsCount = loadedImgsCount + 1`. Same with `imgTotalWidth = imgTotalWidth + currImg.width`: `imgTotalWidth += currImg.width`.

Answer (score 3):

Do the reverse:

```
currImg.onload = function() {
    loadedImgsCount = loadedImgsCount + 1;
    imgTotalWidth = imgTotalWidth + currImg.width;
};
currImg.src = images[i];
```

Your problem is that the `onload` function may not be called when the images are in cache because the `load` event is generated before you set the `onload` callback.

As a side note, it's usual to do this to increment a variable:

```
loadedImgsCount++;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as a width attribute isn't hard-coded, I prefer to check for an image's width to determine if it is loaded. This avoids the caching issues.

```
var
images = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg", "2.jpg"],
images_place = $("#img_place"),  
images_loaded_interval = setInterval(function() {
    var total_width = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        if($('img',images_place).eq(i).width()*1 == 0) return;
        else total_width += $('img',images_place).eq(i).width()*1;

     alert(total_width);
     clearInterval(images_loaded_interval);

}, 500);

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
    images_place.append("<img src='" + images[i] + "'>");
```